# Clean way to cascade divs when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking for a clean way to cascade divs one over the other when scrolling. I found a way to do it but it is anything but clean and I only succeeded for the first one.

This is what I have, observe how the "section 1" goes under the others when scrolling down.

The code I used to get that is, as I said, very messy and it feels like it is the wrong way to do it but here is the main concept:

```
  <div style="left:0;" id="section-1"class="section">
                <h2><a name="1">Section 1</a></h2>
                <p>Blahaha
                </p>
            </div>
            <div style="z-index:-2; height: 100%;"></div>
            <div></div>
```

And also an extra little chunk of css:

```
#section-1{
    position:fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

the `<div></div>` part is to simply not throw this parts of code I have for the rest of  the page:

```
.section:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #dddddd;
}
```

If anybody has some insight on that as well, it would be nice.

I am open to using jquery for this.

Comment: How I interpret the example without examining the code, is Section 1 being z-index 1, the rest of the content z-index 2, and the fixed nav at z-index 3. Additionally the nav and Section 1 have position fixed. If you apply these settings to the usual flow of your document, you should get a very similar result. Remember that you need positioning (that is, absolute, relative or fixed, but not the default static), to apply a z-index to an element.

Comment: @2C-B Yeah its something like that. I just discovered z-indexes exist so my numbers might seem strange but you got the general idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using jquery sticky plugin.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
        <script src="jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".section").sticky({topSpacing:$('#navigation').height()});
  });
</script>
```

This caused a few minor issues with `nthchild()` but that is only an inconvenience for me - the developer and not the users.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling) plugin which provides exactly that way of cascading sections.